# RecyclerView no touch feedback

Tags: android, touch, android-recyclerview

I'm using this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Unfortunately when I press an item **It doesn't show any touch effect.**

I'm working hard on this problem but I can't get my project recyclerview touch feedback to work.

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/material-part-5/

What causes this problem ?

Comment: use selector drawable as background for your item view layout

Comment: i dont know how i can do this? and my problem only when touching item i dont show any touching effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `layout` file for your `RecyclerView` row, trying setting  the `background` attribute for your row as the following:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: Iwas add your code after >>> My style: Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar doesnt work.
After change style the: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar work.